# R: Why does it take so long to parse this data table

Tags: r, optimization

I have a data frame df that has 15 columns and 1000000 rows of all ints. My code is:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
if(is.null(df$col1[i]) || .... || is.null(df$col9[i]))
df[-i,] #to delete the row if one of those columns is null
}
```

This has been running for an hour and is still going. Why? It seems like it should be relatively fast code to run. How can I speed it up?

Comment: can you dput some of your data with NULL value? it's not rather NA?

Comment: Try `df[colSums(is.null(df))==0,]` (not tested). You would also need to reassign df in your loop, otherwise, those rows are not deleted. Generally, `for` loops are not very fast in R, especially when applied to each row in a 15x1e6 table..

Comment: Your code isn't working. Are you assigning df[-i,] to anything? Even if you do, think what is going to happen if you delete row1, when i becomes 2?

Comment: This seem like an poor way to filter rows. It would be better if you took a step back and better described what you are trying to do. Include a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output. Start small.

Comment: ... of course I meant `df[rowSums(is.null(df))==0,]`, not `colSums`.. but apparently, that doesn't work (tested on mtcars)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is slow is that R is relatively slow at looping through vectors.  Most functions in R are vectorized which means you can perform them on a vector at once much faster than it can loop through each element one by one.  On a side note, I don't think you have NULLs in your data frame.  I think you have NAs so I'm going to assume that is what you have.  Even if you have NULLs then the following should still work.

This syntax should give you a nice speed boost.
This will take advantage of `rowSums` producing NA for every row that has missing values in it.

```
df<-subset(df, !is.na(rowSums(df[,1:10])))
```

This syntax should also work.

```
df<-df[rowSums(is.na(df[,1:10]))==0,]
```

Comment: @user3000877 if this explanation answers your question would you consider accepting it.  If not, could you let us know what extra clarification could be provided?

Comment: The looping isn’t the slow part here. What’s slow is the constant copying of a whole data frame (minus one row), which is what I’m assuming is happening (although OP’s code doesn’t show this).